# Attachments for bamboo test reports

Tags: selenium, bamboo

I'm trying to attach selenium screenshots to test reports on Bamboo. For Jenkins I used [Junit attachments plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Attachments+Plugin). Now I'm looking for something similar for bamboo. Does anybody know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

For now the best way is to use Bamboo artifacts as suggested here:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/244361/screenshots-for-selenium-tests

There is also an issue to implement attaching screenshots to test results:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13108

you can vote for it